# Does EF Core supports XOR relationship constraint?

Tags: entity-framework, xor, ef-core-7.0

I can't find any information about the support of EF Core 7 for XOR relationship constraint.

Is the following relationship supported?

[image]

Comment: Depends on how you want to implement it in a database schema.